# Spring Data JPA ManyToOne and OneToMany - Unable to find entity with ID

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have three tables - `role`, `user`, and `user_role`. This is supposed to be `ManyToMany` but since I also want to generate id for the `user_role`, I used `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne`.

Here are my entities with relevant fields only:

```
@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "role")
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles;
}

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles;
}

@Entity
public class UserRole {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Role role;  
}
```

Then, this is how I create instances of them and save to the DB:

```
// Retrieve from DB by ID
Role role = ...;

// ID String is generated from UUID
User user = new User();
user.id("abc");

// ID String is generated from UUID
UserRole userRole = new UserRole();
userRole.setId("xyz");

Set<UserRole> userRoles = Set.of(userRole);

role.setUserRoles(userRoles);
user.setUserRoles(userRoles);

userRole.setUser(user);
userRole.setRole(role);

userRepository.save(user);
```

The issue that I find it difficult to resolve no matter how I have tried and googled:

```
2020-09-27 23:41:58.917  WARN 21948 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find com.example.entity.UserRole with id xyz; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.example.entity.UserRole with id xyz]
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Try to add `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` to the `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`

Comment: @SternK only User? how about Role?

Comment: Wow! It works. I believed I'd done that but the difference, I also added it to role. But now I added it only to User and it's working.

Comment: I can confirm adding the same to Role gives another issue. So adding cascade to User is enough. Thank you.

Comment: @Julez  Did u find any answer??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73234549/javax-persistence-entitynotfoundexception-unable-to-find-entity-with-id

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned elsewhere you need to se minimum:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<UserRole> userRoles;
```

or minimum:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user" , cascade = 
        CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<UserRole> userRoles;
```

But also if you need to fetch `UserRoles` by `User` you need to set:

```
// for each UserRole in the list.
userRole.setUser(user);
```

before persisting otherwise list will not be populated.

Answer (score 3):

Stern has good point. You are trying to save **only** `user` entity, but you don't have any cascade set anywhere. So when you call `userRepository.save(user)` it is obviously missing role entities. Either save dependent entities before saving `user`, or better, add cascade above `userRoles` field in your User class etc.