# Spring Hibernate: Unable to find entity with Id even data available in the database (Only in one to many relationship)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, database-relations

In the spring boot project I have 2 entities named `Assessment` and `Request` andtheir relationship is defined as given below.

```java
    @Entity
    public class Assessment {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
        private Long id;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "arequest_id")
        @JsonIgnore
        private Request request;

        // getters and setters and rest of the properties
    }
```

and the Request class defined as given below (Please note that this relationship is only defined in Assessment)

```java
@Entity
public class Request {
    @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
        private Long id;
       
        // Getters and setters along with the rest of the properties
        // No relationship defined here for the Assessment class

}
```

Then for my requirement, I need to get all the assessments by Request.id for that I create the following method as a derived query.

```java
public List<CandidateAssessment> findAllByRequestId(long requested);
```

But when I run the program it gives the following error message for the Request IDs that have data in the request table and assessment data in the database. The interesting part is for the requests that do not have data in assessment it shows an empty array but for the requests that contain assessments, it always gives the following error.

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.example.entity.Request with id 127
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1106) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1025) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:716) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:502) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1115) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:973) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
```

I know I can define it as a bidirectional and call for request first and then call the `getAssessments` method to fetch the data but this cannot be work like that.

And there are several other entities that implemented as same but working without issue.

How can I fix this issue?

### Note

I have tried following the methods

1. add bidirectional definition to entity management
2. tried different method derived queries like `findAllByRequest_Id`
3. Try to write manual queries with @Query annotation with JPA queries and native queries.
4. tried some answers given in following questions, but so far no idea to resolve this issue.

   - [EntityNotFoundException in Hibernate Many To One mapping however data exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539050/entitynotfoundexception-in-hibernate-many-to-one-mapping-however-data-exist)
   - [Hibernate - unable to find Entity with ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46612968/hibernate-unable-to-find-entity-with-id)
   - [Spring Data JPA ManyToOne and OneToMany - Unable to find entity with ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64090756/spring-data-jpa-manytoone-and-onetomany-unable-to-find-entity-with-id)

Comment: Have you tried logging the generated queries by JPA to see if they're correct?

Comment: The problem is you named your field `Request` and not `request` hence the derived query looks for the field `request` but doesn't find that.

Comment: @M.Deinum sorry, that was a typo in my question.

Comment: So this isn't actual code but a modified and dumbed down version of it? Your method returns `List<CandidateAssesment>` but that entity/dto isn't in your question. I also wonder which Spring Boot version you are using as you seem to be using quite an old version of Hibernate.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, it is a kind of dumbed-down version but the only change is that variable names which are not with standards and are kind of lengthy. The spring boot version is 1.3.5 and as you mentioned way older version. And if you think exact coding would be great I can edit and add it.

Comment: Well the problem with dumbed down versions and the fact that you think it is only the names that changed that often that isn't the case (and lead to things like wrong names in code as my earlier comment). Also if they are not with standards do they actually match the hibernate naming strategies.